# Test Execution should not stop if validations point in test case fail it should log the failure and continue with remaining script in robot framework

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, robotframework

I have some validation points in my test case. The test case execution should not stop even if the validation parts are getting failed it should log failure message and continue with remaining script

```
*** Test Cases ***
Validating Dropdown
    ${sums}=  ['1234','455','4689','9837']
    ${sum2}=  ['1234','455','46','9837']

    ${sum_count}=  Get Length  ${sums}
    FOR  ${i}  IN RANGE  ${sum_count}
        ${sums}[${i}]==${sum2}[${i}]
    END

    ${sums3}=  ['12','455','4689','9837']
    ${sum4}=  ['34','455','46','9837']

    ${sum_count1}=  Get Length  ${sums3}
    FOR  ${i}  IN RANGE  ${sum_count}
        ${sums3}[${i}]==${sum4}[${i}]
    END
    ${sums5}=  ['1234','455','4689','9837']
    ${sum6}=  ['1234','455','4689','9837']

    ${sum_count2}=  Get Length  ${sums5}
    FOR  ${i}  IN RANGE  ${sum_count}
        ${sums5}[${i}]==${sum6}[${i}]
    END
```

The entire script will run in for loop it should not stop even if the particular validation fails it should continue with the script and log result of each validation whether it is failed or passed

The entire script will run in for loop it should not stop execution even if the particular validation fails it should continue with the script and log result of each validation whether it is failed or passed in Robot Framrwork

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You test is failing due to syntax error. This is the error:

```
========================================================================================
Validating Dropdown                                                             | FAIL |
No keyword with name '${sums}= ['1234','455','4689','9837']' found.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Validate Continue                                                               | FAIL |
1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
=======================================================================================
```

And inside each loop you are not calling a keyword. It will also fail.

This should be a possible corrected test case:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Validating Dropdown
    ${collector}=    Create List
    Set Test Variable    \${collector}
    ${sums}=    Create List    '1234'    '455'    '4689'    '9837'
    ${sum2}=    Create List    '1234'    '455'    '46'    '9837'
    ${sum_count}=    Get Length    ${sums}
    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    ${sum_count}
        ${result}=    Run Keyword And Continue On Failure    Validate Equal    ${sums}[${i}]    ${sum2}[${i}]
        Run Keyword If    "${result[0]}" == "FAIL"    Append To List    ${collector}    ${result}
    END
    # Report
    ${sums3}=    Create List    '12'    '455'    '4689'    '9837'
    ${sum4}=    Create List    '34'    '455'    '46'    '9837'
    ${sum_count1}=    Get Length    ${sums3}
    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    ${sum_count1}
        ${result}=    Run Keyword And Continue On Failure    Validate Equal    ${sums3}[${i}]    ${sum4}[${i}]
        Run Keyword If    "${result[0]}" == "FAIL"    Append To List    ${collector}    ${result}
    END
    # Report
    ${sums5}=    Create List    '1234'    '455'    '4689'    '9837'
    ${sum6}=    Create List    '1234'    '455'    '4689'    '9837'
    ${sum_count2}=    Get Length    ${sums5}
    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    ${sum_count2}
        ${result}=    Run Keyword And Continue On Failure    Validate Equal    ${sums3}[${i}]    ${sum4}[${i}]
        Run Keyword If    "${result[0]}" == "FAIL"    Append To List    ${collector}    ${result}
    END
    Report

*** Keywords ***
Validate Equal
    [Arguments]    ${arg1}    ${arg2}
    ${result}=    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Should Be Equal    ${arg1}    ${arg2}
    RETURN    ${result}

Report
    ${fail_count}=    Get Length    ${collector}
    IF    ${fail_count} > 0
        Log Many    @{collector}
        Fail    Validation of elements failed. Some are different
    END
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually i have written a long script and script is in FOR loop to validate each option from dropdown in that I have some validation points. If the validation point fails it should continue with the remaining script and should not not stop until and unless there is error in script if the validation part fails it should log that this step is failed and continue with the script the entire program should not get failed

Comment: can i use the same code if it is not a list?

Comment: It is a matter of adaptation and experimentation.